# Use RMSE in Gradient Boosting

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, xgboost, loss-function

Is it possible to use the *RMSE* loss function in *XGBoost* or in sklearn's *GradientBoostingRegressor* as is done in *CatBoost*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use rmse for XGBoost. RMSE is used there in the `eval_metric` for the regression and error in classification.

Reference: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html?highlight=rmse